# Como migrar Colunas Long Raw Oracle 11G

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Preciso migrar informações de um coluna do tipo `long raw oracle 11g`.

```sql
CREATE TABLE PROD_IMAGEM (
    ID NUMERIC(8),
    IMAGEM LONG RAW
);

CREATE TABLE BKP_TAB_IMAGEM (
    ID NUMERIC(8),
    IMAGEM LONG RAW
);

DECLARE
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
BEGIN
  Insert into BKP_TAB_IMAGEM (ID, IMAGEM) values (1,IMAGE_L);
END;
```

**O Erro apresenta do e o seguinte:**
Erro na Linha de Comandos :

```
2 Coluna : 231 Relatório de erros - Erro de SQL: ORA-01704: 
literal de string extenso demais
01704. 00000 -  "string literal too long"
*Cause:    The string literal is longer than 4000 characters.
*Action:   Use a string literal of at most 4000 characters.
           Longer values may only be entered using bind variables.
```

Comment: por favor esclareça: você quer migrar do 11g para 18c, OCI 18c??? outro Oracle? outra versão? ou fazer um backup? Existem formas melhores de fazer isso. Se for backup, desta forma está totalmente "sem integridade".

Comment: Preciso restaurar algumas linhas deletadas da tabela PROD_IMAGEM essas informações já existe na tabela BKP_TAB_IMAGEM.

Comment: Tenta a UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/u_raw.htm

Comment: Tentei nesse formato e não deu certo  

`insert into PROD_IMAGEM (select id, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(IMAGEM)) from BKP_TAB_IMAGEM);`  

insert into PROD_IMAGEM (select id, utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(IMAGEM)) from BKP_TAB_IMAGEM)
Erro na Linha de Comandos : 17 Coluna : 78
Relatório de erros -
Erro de SQL: ORA-00997: uso inválido do tipo de dados LONG
00997. 00000 -  "illegal use of LONG datatype"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Answer (score 0):

A solução que fiz pois tinha um legado deste tipo foi algo como :

```
create or replace FUNCTION OBTER_TEXTO_XYZ (P_CHAVE IN NUMBER) RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
  /*
  FAZ A CONVERSAO NECESSARIA DO TIPO LONG RAW (TIPO DESCONTINUAD) PARA VARCHAR2 - PARA SER USADO EM QUERIES
  */
  VS_XYZ  VARCHAR2(4000);
  VLR_XYZ LONG RAW;
BEGIN
  SELECT XYZ_TEXTO 
  INTO VLR_XYZ 
  FROM XYZ WHERE CHAVE  = P_CHAVE;

  begin
    VS_XYZ := UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2(VLR_XYZ);
  EXCEPTION
    when OTHERS then
      VS_XYZ := '<TEXTO MUITO LONGO>';
  END;  
  RETURN VS_XYZ;
END;
```

aí se faz um select do tipo

```
select obter_texto_xyz(chavexyz) memo from xyz where ...
```

Funciona para textos , mas a package UTL_RAW deve ter algo para outros formatos, nunca precisei.

Comment: Obrigado Motta já e um caminho, porem no meu caso quero migrar toda a informação dessa coluna do banco para outro banco.